# PDF for the positive part of $X \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability

Define $Y$ to be the positive part of a random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$.

So

$$
Y = \max(X, 0)
$$

If $X < 0$, then $Y = 0$, and this occurs with probability $0.5$. If $X \geq 0$, then $Y = X$, and in this situation I believe $Y$ just has the PDF corresponding to the right half of $N(0,1)$.

I want to find $f_{Y|X > 0}$ mathematically, but I'm struggling to. I tried using Bayes rule (I use $f$ to indicate a PDF and $P$ to indicate probability)
$$
f_{Y|X > 0} = \frac{f(Y, X > 0)}{P(X > 0)} = 2f(Y, X > 0) = 2f(X > 0 | Y)f(Y)
$$

I don't know what $f(X > 0 | Y)$ or $f(Y)$ is in this situation, and I'm not confident about the last inequality. It looks off to me, specifically the $f(X > 0 | Y)$ term.

Note that I know the possibly more "proper" approach would be to find the CDF of $X|X>0$, but I am particularly curious about my PDF case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional density of the rv $X|X>0$ is simply

$$f_{X|X>0}(t)=2\cdot f_X(x)$$

and the proof is very simple...

---

$$F_{X|X>0}(t)=\frac{P(X\leq t;X>0)}{P(X>0)}=\frac{F_X(t)-F_X(0)}{1/2}$$

derivating you get your density

$$f_X(t)=2f_X(t)$$

$t>0$

Comment: So this means $f(Y, X > 0) = f(X, X > 0) = f_X$? I understand what $f_X$ means, but $f(X, X > 0)$ looks weird to me.

Comment: I just saw your edit. Sorry, I should've mentioned this in the OP that I know how to solve the problem using Bayes Rule with the CDFs, but I'm specifically confused about the pdf case.

Comment: @user5965026: added some details in my answer. I calculated the conditional density, give that $X>0$. Different situation is if yuo want to derive the distribution of $Y$; observe that $Y$ does not admit a density

Comment: Regarding your latter comment, doesn't $Y$ admit a density half the time, and the other half, it's just a point mass with probability $0.5$?

Comment: @user5965026. Yes, $Y$ does not adimt a density because it is not absolutely continuous: it has a positive probability mass in $Y=0$. In some applications they define for such a rv a "mixed density"